# Beginner: Pointers and General Syntax in C Programming

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

Can someone please help me understand what this is doing:

```
alt_up_sd_card_dev *dev = (alt_up_sd_card_dev *) alt_find_dev(name, &alt_dev_list);
if (dev != NULL)
{
     aux_status_register = ((short int *) SD_CARD_AUX_STATUS(dev->base));
}
```

I understand that the `(short int *)` is "type-casting" (as explained to me by some other helpful people on this forum) what `SD_CARD_AUX_STATUS` should be when the contents are called, but I've never seen the dev->base syntax before....

Comment: Look around for C tutorials (or a good C text, find suggestions at the sidebar). Jumping in with both feet as tou seem to do is ill advised.

Answer (score 1):

1.Here dev, is structure pointer. This pointer gets the memory from this line  (alt_up_sd_card_dev *) alt_find_dev(name, &alt_dev_list);

2.The structure alt_up_sd_card_dev  may have member called base.

3.SD_CARD_AUX_STATUS could be  macro, which does some manipulation on dev->base pointer.
For more information, check the parameterised MACRO concepts in C

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to C syntax in general. This piece of code is very specific.

I can only guess what it does.

```
alt_up_sd_card_dev *dev = (alt_up_sd_card_dev *) alt_find_dev(name, &alt_dev_list);
```

This calls a function `alt_find_dev` which probably looks for a device. The device is apparently an sd card reader... The result of the function is cast to a specific type of pointer. Probably the result is of generic pointer type and it is cast to a pointer to a structure that describes specifically an sd card device. It is then stored in the `dev` variable.

```
if (dev != NULL)
```

if the device is found....

```
aux_status_register = ((short int *) SD_CARD_AUX_STATUS(dev->base));
```

a macro `SD_CARD_AUX_STATUS` is called with a parameter `dev->base` (where `base` is a field in the structure describing the sd card device). The operator `->` is called pointer dereference and it is simillar to `.` operator. It allows to access fields of a struct which is pointed by the pointer. The macro returns some kind of a status of the device. Hard to tell why it is cast to a pointer to short int, but the result is stored in a variable `aux_status_register`.

Without additional information it's impossible to tell anything more about the code.

Answer (score 0):

We can't give you a proper answer without knowing all the include files this references, but by general convention:

1) By standard C naming conventions, the all-uppercase `SD_CARD_AUX_STATUS()` is a macro rather than a function. The macro is set up by a `#define` either earlier in this file or in one of the `#include`d `.h` files. Look for that definition to find out what it's actually doing.

2) -> is like . but for pointers-to-structures rather than structures. That is, if you have a `struct  { int foo, bar; } baz`, then `baz.foo` is the same thing as `(&baz)->foo` Or, as Wikipedia puts it:

```
Structure dereference ("member b of object pointed to by a")    a->b    
Structure reference ("member b of object a")                    a.b
```

Answer (score 0):

dev is a pointer to a data structure in memory - called a struct in C. A struct has members - a set of variables within it. dev->base means access the member called base within the struct of type alt_up_sd_card_dev which dev is pointing to.

Look for the definition of struct alt_up_sd_card_dev which you will find in one of the header files included from the one you are looking at.

In general the -> operator is said to de-reference the pointer.

SD_CARD_AUX_STATUS is probably a macro - traditionally these are named all upper case. It might perform some kind of conversion or even call a function. Search for its definition in the headers.